# spring data cassandra connectivity along with datastax opscenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have already installed Cassandra in Ubuntu 15.10, created a cluster and established spring data connectivity . How can I use Opscenter for monitoring of same cluster?

Answer (score 0):

To monitor a cassandra cluster with the opscenter you need to:

1. Install opscenter in a machine (does not need to be a node in the cluster). In ubuntu you can just use the datastax repository:

   $ echo "deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/datastax.community.list

   $ curl -L https://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key | sudo apt-key add -

   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install opscenter

   $ sudo service opscenterd start

You can connect to the opscenter by the next url: http://opscenter-host:8888/

2. Add an existing cluster to the opscenter.
3. Install the datastax agents in each of the nodes. This can be done throught the opscenter or just manually installing it in each node:

   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install datastax-agent